# Azure Pipelines select agent to run build on within pool yml template

Tags: deployment, yaml, azure-pipelines

Im struggling to find any documentation to select a specific build agent that's in a given pool via our yaml azure pipeline file. Right now were selecting the pull to launch the job on but I'm having massive deployment issues with our servers and need to individually select the one I want to run the job on have anyone ever had to do something like this before?

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    exclude:
    - README.md

pool: 'ZupaDeploymentPool'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to make your pipeline run on a specific build agent. See below steps:

1, Specify a user defined capability (you can use the System capabilities too)

Go to **Project Setting**s-->**Agent pools** of **Pipelines**-->Select your **Agent Pool**-->Go to **Agents** tab--Select your **Agent**-->Click **Capabilities**-->Click `**+**` to add a user defined capability. See this the detailed steps and screenshots [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-make-sure-i-have-the-latest-v2-agent-version).

[image]

Then you can define the demands in your yaml pipeline like below: The pipeline will only run on the build agent which i defined the capability `Tag = agent1` in above step.

```
pool: 
  name: agengPoolName
  demands: 
  - Tag -equals agent1
```

You can also use the **system capabilities** without defining your own capabilities in demands. See below i use the system capabilities `Agent.Name`

```
 pool:
   name: Default
   demands: 
   - Agent.Name -equals myagentName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this was struggling to find the system argument names in the docs but that looks like it's all working.

Comment: Is it possible for the pipeline to determine which agent is available in the pool? Say I have an agent pool with two agents installed. If one my pipelines is using agent1 to run the build and another pipeline has been triggered, is there a way to configure it in such a way that if it sees that agent1 is being used then it will use agent2 instead, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with the UI but not when coding it in YAML but the concepts will be applicable:

You put the Agent.Name you are trying to select into the Build -> Options -> Demands section of the pipeline definition. In the UI it reads like

```
Agent.Name        equals       Foo
```

Based on that demand, that build will only go to the specified agent within the pool...

For the YAML-defined Build, the [Demands are defined as shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).