# YAML for Azure Pipeline for MonoRepo code on a self-hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm a first time user of Azure Devops and I need to create a CI/CD process for a mono-repo project hosted on Azure Repos. Here's a brief description

- The Git repo has multiple projects inside it that I would like to build in separate pipelines as they have separate makefiles and no inter-dependencies. Eg. Project layout

RepoA

```
LinuxProject

FirmwareProject

TestProject
```

- I have a self-hosted Azure agent (RepoABuild) with all the tools installed that I would like to build these projects on.
- The requirement of LinuxProject YAML file is

  - Trigger a build when a source change happens only within LinuxProject directory
  - Use Agent RepoABuild to do build
  - Execute bash commands "cd RepoA/LinuxProject", "source opt/lib/linux/settings.sh" and "make images"
  - Archive the artifacts present in the "RepoA/LinuxProject/Build" directory

Can Anyone here help me with this requirement or point me to any example ? I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow below steps to create the yaml pipeline for LinuxProject:

1, Create a yaml file and commit to your azure repo (eg.LinuxProject-pipeline.yml).

2, Create a yaml pipeline from your azure project portal.

> Sign in to your Azure DevOps organization and navigate to your project.
>
> In your project, navigate to the **Pipelines** page. Then choose the action to create a **new pipeline**.
>
> Walk through the steps of the wizard by first selecting **Azure Repos Git** as the location of your source code.
>
> Walk through the steps of the wizard and Choose **Existing Azure Pipelines Yaml file**. And select file `LinuxProject-pipeline.yml` created in the 1st step in the prompted window.

[image]

3, Add below content to LinuxProject-pipeline.yml file.

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - LinuxProject/*

pool: your-self-hosted-agent-pool

steps:

- bash: |
    cd RepoA/LinuxProject
    source opt/lib/linux/settings.sh
    make images

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/LinuxProject/Build
    archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/LinuxProject.zip
```

In above yaml file, the **trigger** defines a path filter which makes the pipeline only be triggered when changes happens in folder LinuxProject. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#triggers) for more information about **trigger**

The **pool**, define its value to the name of agent pool where your self-hosted agent(RepoABuild) resides. (Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939699/azure-pipelines-select-agent-to-run-build-on-within-pool-yml-template/61947254#61947254) to use demands if you have multiple self-hosted agents in the agent pool)

Add [bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) task to run the bash commands

Add [ArchiveFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) task to archive your build result.

You might need to change above yaml file a little bit according to your project. You can refer to below steps to create pipelines for the other two projects.

Please check out the [get started document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cyaml%2Cbrowser%2Ctfs-2018-2) to start with.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops) are the key pipeline basic concepts.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) is the Yaml schema reference.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) are the predefined variables you can use in your pipeline directly(eg. $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in above archive file task refers to foler `c:\agent_work\1\a` in your agent machine).

Comment: Is there a way to automatically give version number and increment the version numbers of these artifacts for e.g 1.0.0b0, 1.0.0b1 ?

Comment: What does "@2" signify in ArchiveFiles@2 target. I observed if I use  ArchiveFiles@1, then the zip directory is empty. It seems like it specifies ordering constraint of the pipeline steps. Can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: You can use [Counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter) for auto increment versioning. You can aslo use the predefined variable `$(build.buildid)`  or [$(Build.BuildNumber)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: `@2` signifies the version of the task.

Comment: @ Levi Lu-MSFT As part of archiving the build I would also like to make the LinuxProject.zip available under Azure Artifacts. I tried using universalPackages approach but facing issues with it. Can you take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62072310/azure-pipelines-universal-package-task-fails-with-error-the-package-name-provid